# Difference between File>Close and :close in Vim

Tags: vim

I opened `_gvimrc` from Vim's HOME folder.
Made a small edit.
Escaped from edit mode.
Executed `:w` to save the change.
Then tried to close the file by executing `:close` but it says `E444: Cannot close last window`

If I go to the File menu and click the menuitem `Close` (which says `:close` next to it) then it closes fine.

Why does File>Close close the file happily but `:close` does not?

---

**EDIT**

This is my File menu:

[image]

Comment: PROTIP: forget menus and force yourself to use Ex commands instead, `:w`, `:q`, `:bd` and so on. Read the help for all these commands, `:h :w` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from `:he :close`:

`CTRL-W c                    *CTRL-W_c* *:clo* *:close*
:clo[se][!] Close current window.  When the 'hidden' option is set, or
        when the buffer was changed and the [!] is used, the buffer
        becomes hidden (unless there is another window editing it).
        When there is only one window in the current tab page and
        there is another tab page, this closes the current tab page.
        |tab-page|.
        This command fails when:            *E444*
        - There is only one window on the screen.
        - When 'hidden' is not set, [!] is not used, the buffer has
          changes, and there is no other window on this buffer.
        Changes to the buffer are not written and won't get lost, so
        this is a "safe" command.`

basically, the menu item `close window` is misname and matches what is actually `:quit` that closes current window, or the current vim session if this is the last window:

`*:q* *:quit*
:q[uit]         Quit the current window.  Quit Vim if this is the last
            window.  This fails when changes have been made and
            Vim refuses to |abandon| the current buffer, and when
            the last file in the argument list has not been
            edited.
            If there are other tab pages and quitting the last
            window in the current tab page the current tab page is
            closed |tab-page|.
            Triggers the |QuitPre| autocommand event.`

and IINW, it's actually `:confirm quit`. So if you're right about having `:close` next to the `close` menu option, that certainly is a typo that shall be patched.

EDIT:

ok, just had a discussion with some people on #vim IRC channel. There, I have been informed about the `:menu` command, from where you can access the file->close command, through `:menu File.Close`:

```
To create a new menu item, use the ":menu" commands.  They are mostly like
the ":map" set of commands but the first argument is a menu item name, given
as a path of menus and submenus with a '.' between them, e.g.: >

:menu File.Save  :w<CR>
:inoremenu File.Save  <C-O>:w<CR>
:menu Edit.Big\ Changes.Delete\ All\ Spaces  :%s/[ ^I]//g<CR>
```

The closing operation is definitely not `:close`, but a builtin for menus being `WinClose` (`BuiltIn17`), `:he builtin-tools`. It does things differently from `:close`.

But anyway, that bug/typo apart, if you're new to vim, you'd better learn to use it without the menus. Everything you need is under your finger tips. Go through `vimtutor`, play at `vimgolf`, read some tutorials, and try to learn and use one new command each month. You'll end up more productive and forget about your mouse…

Comment: +1 thanks for this. I've added a screenprint to OP. Even `:q` errors for me saying `E37: No write sonce last change (add ! to override)`

Comment: `:confirm quit` closes the whole app - I only want to close the file

Comment: or maybe what `:close` is actually closer to `:bdel` which closes the current buffer. I'm not sure, as I don't use `gvim`, and don't have one… but when you do `File->Close` you get the last file closed and get an empty buffer instead? in any cases, it looks to me like a bug in `gvim` that shall be patched.

Comment: if you want to correct the menu item information, here's a suggestion from IRC: `:tmenu File.Close Execute :close or :enew (on last window)` ;-)