# Executing Python with Gvim

Tags: python, windows, vim

- open gVim.
- then using the File Menu and MenuItem Open to open a
  file pi.py which has the following tiny script:

[image]

How do I execute this code using gVim?

---

**EDIT**

If I use either `:! python pi.py` or `:w !python -` then I get the following:

[image]

Comment: @SatA - apologies - correct Gvim

Comment: @Will Hardy solution seems to work :)

Comment: @SatA - on my machine if I type `:w !python` then I get the error I've added to the OP. Do you think I need to configure Vim more so that it finds the python interpretter?

Comment: Hey, yes, I just added a proposal for a solution, does that help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to save the file, you can run the current buffer as stdin to a command such as `python` by typing:

```
:w !python -
```

(The hyphen at the end probably isn't necessary, python will generally use stdin by default)

edit: seeing as you are new to vim, note that this will not save the file, it will just run it. You will probably want to learn how to save your file.

Comment: If you're using Windows, I can't help you much, but I assume you don't have python installed in a place listed in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I thought `:w` was save file? ...so why isn't `:w !python` the equivalent of `save file`+`run python`?

Comment: `:w` means write, `:w myfile.py` means write to the file called `myfile.py` and `:w !somecommand` means "write" to the command `somecommand`. It won't save to file, it will send the current state to the given command, ie `python`.

Comment: thanks will - although this difference must be quite subtle? if I open a file and edit it, then use `:w`, then close the file (Vim does not ask about saving changes), then re-open the file I find that my changes are still there - the changes have been saved. So how does "saving" do more than `:w`?

Comment: also Will - have a look at my screen print in [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385420/difference-between-fileclose-and-close-in-vim) ...next to `Save` it says `:w`?

Comment: `:w !somecommand` doesn't save your file to disk. It "writes" it to the command you gave after `:w`. What comes after the `:w` changes its behaviour. `:w` alone will save your changes to disk, which is what you probably want anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If you have python support compiled into vim you can use `:pyfile %` to run the current file. (python 2.7)

If you have python 3 support use `:py3file %` instead

[pyfile help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#%3apyfile)

Comment: ..how do I know if python is compiled into gvim? is this something I need to do myself?

Comment: Type echo `has("python")` or `has("python3")`. If you have python 2.7 support the first will return `1`. If you have python3 support the second will return `1`. Otherwise it returns `0`. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718122/how-to-enable-python-support-in-gvim-on-windows)

Comment: `echo has("python")` returns 1 ...I have only just added `;C:\python27\;` to my environ pathways which seems to have helped. +1 for the nice reference

Comment: `:pyfile %` works fine - whereas `:w !python` runs it in the console your answer runs it in gvim

Answer (score 4):

Something like this. Type following command in vi command model.

```
:! python test.py
```

Comment: if I change test.py to my actual filename pi.py then I get an `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`....should I add the directory where I store my `.py` files to my PCs environ pathways?

Comment: well if I run `:w pi.py` in gvim then it errors...but if I run just `:w` then it tells me that it has saved the file

Answer (score 2):

It seems your %path% environment variable doesn't contain your python installation path.

Follow the following steps:

1. Right-Click "My Computer"
2. Choose "Properties"
3. Goto the advanced settings
4. Goto "Environment Variables"
5. Select "PATH" and click on "Edit"
6. Add the following to the end of the line: ";C:\python27\;" (without quotes)

Note: change the directory to your python directory (could be c:\python30, for example)

**Save everything and then - Close vim and all CMDs and try again.**

Comment: No need to.. Try it without restart first :)

Comment: (although now the environ path is set I'm actually using Hardy's answer to run the code!)

Comment: Its best to combine the two solutions together. As Hardy's answer is very interesting and informative AND answers your basic question ;)

Comment: - what: write my own solution combining both your answers? ...then neither of you get the points.